# AWS Automatically Generating New Instance After I Terminate It.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

OK, odd thing is happening on AWS.

I downloaded the AWS .NET developer tools and created an elastic beanstalk default instance. 
I then, for one reason or another, created another instance via the Visual Studio interface and that instance is where all the clients code / configurations reside. I then returned to the default instance created by elastic beanstalk and terminated it. An hour later, I logged back on and another default instance was up and running. It seems that AWS has detected that I terminated the instance and has spawned another. Some sort of check seems to be in place. 
Can somebody tell me what is going on here and how to completely remove the default instance (and its termination protection behavior)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've experienced something similar. If the instance was created through Elastic Beanstalk, you need to go the Elastic Beanstalk screen in the AWS console and remove the application from there first. If you just terminate the instance from the EC2 screen, Elastic Beanstalk probably thinks that the instance crashed and launches a new one.

Comment: Aaaahh... yes. I was trying to terminate the instance without terminating the elastic beanstalk default environment / application first. Looks like it is working as expected now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created it and forgot that I created it from elastic beanstalk

Answer (score 4):

if beanstalk is not enable, then most probably it is creating from auto scaling. which is present in EC2 service itself.

Go to auto scaling and first delete the auto configuration group and launch configuration for that associate instance.

Comment: Clears my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/718792/465296) it is caused by `Auto Scaling Group`'s desired/minimum 1 instance setting. So, what that means is that the instances in that auto scaling group will always have a running instance. If you delete the only one it will create another one. To prevent this go to EC2 dashboard and on the left sidebar scroll down to find/click `Auto Scaling Groups` under `AUTO SCALING` menu. You will see the list of groups where you can click on them to see which instances are in those groups. Find the group that your instance is in and either delete it (that happens when an environment is deleted as well) or change its desired and minimum 1 instance rule to 0 and save. That is it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your autoscaling groups. If you would have created node groups for your EKS cluster.