# Default Instances are re-initiating continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using **Amazon EC2** *free tier* package. By default they have an instance there. they named it 'Default Environment'. But each time when I am terminating that **instance** then it is being initiated again.

But in my *free tier* package they provide 1 instance. But If I want to create a new instance then it charged me cause still there is a **Default Environment** instance exist. But I can't terminated that. When terminated after sometimes it creates again automatically. Also it's using my 8GB storage. So I can use my own chosen OS or instance there.

My 1 instance offer has been filled up with their **default instance**.

So can anybody tell me how to get rid of their existing/default instance and I will create my own?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks exactly like [this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481886/aws-automatically-generating-new-instance-after-i-terminate-it) Do you use Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Yes that was created from Elastic Beanstalk. And now It's solved after terminating that from `Elastic Beanstalk`. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the instance was created through Elastic Beanstalk, you need to go the Elastic Beanstalk screen in the AWS console and remove the application from there first. If you just terminate the instance from the EC2 screen, Elastic Beanstalk probably thinks that the instance crashed and launches a new one.

Comment: Thanks David. I forgot about that. To try Amazon ec2 first time I created that from Elastic Beanstalk. Now I terminated that and now I can create my instance. There is no more any default environment. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 2):

if you don't find any application in Elastic beanstalk as David said, probably it is taking from **Auto scaling**.It is present in EC2 service itself.

You need to delete Launch configuration from Auto scaling. First you need to delete auto scaling group which is associate with the launch configuration which is responsible for auto deployment of your terminate instance. then finally you can delete launch configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think their default instance is taking all of the storage.

Comment: No. When I am terminating that EBS says it's available. but after few seconds it's saying in-use again.
And it's being used by auto created their default instance. It's making me weird.

Comment: Really it's weird if it's really happens to you.

Answer (score 0):

The cause (and there might be more) is that the EC2 instance is referenced by Elastic Beanstalk as one of the environments. In my case, I was trying to terminate an environment directly in EC2. However, that instance was used by an application under Elastic Beanstalk as one of the environments and so every time I terminated the EC2 instance, a new EC2 instance was spun up. I resolved this by terminating the application from **Elastic Beanstalk** rather than directly in EC2.

That worked.