# Amazon AWS EC2 instance relaunches when terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an instance that I have never actually launched myself that tends to start each time once I terminate it. This is annoying, as I would need to pay for it and customer service does not reply. Had anyone got a similar question before?

Comment: is it in a auto scaling group?

Comment: "Had anyone got a similar question before?" maybe once http://serverfault.com/questions/718773/terminated-ec2-instances-keep-restarting or twice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481886/aws-automatically-generating-new-instance-after-i-terminate-it or like 100 other times. Did you search at all before posting your question?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=124327

Comment: I have searched of course, but all the threads are related to Elastic Beanstalk and mine has nothing to do with it. And I have no active auto scaling groups.

Comment: If you're terminating an instance and a different one automatically starts up again, the most obvious answer is that it's behind an autoscale group.  In fact, that's really the only obvious answer.  Other (unlikely) possibilities, are someone is messing with you; hacked into your account and is sitting there starting new instances or there is an application out there monitoring your instances and recreating them.  Odds are, it's an autoscale group.  Double check the autoscale groups, double check the elastic beanstalk console.  Try logging into the server and stopping vs. terminating.

Comment: autoscaling or persistent spot instances. but there's insufficient information to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the aid of help of the Amazon Support the problem was resolved. It appears that is you have an instance constantly appearing after being terminated and you have **no active Autoscale groups**, you should cancel it via the new Spot console (beta, the one you access via "Try it out" button), as most likely it is the fleet instance. I'll leave it here in case it is helpful to the others having the same issue.